# packing the packages in a jar file with a manifest file

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I have 4 packages each containing some `.class` files. There is one package that contains `main` class. How do i create a jar file packed with all the folders and the manifest file ?

I know the command `jar cvfm MyJar.jar manifest.txt *.class` , but i don't know the procedure to pack all the folders with their class files.

Here is the scene :

[image]

Also where shall i place the `manifest` file ?

Comment: It should be under META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. I would recommend to use Maven for building jar here.

Comment: why don't you use IDE like Eclipse, it is much easier doing so with an IDE, i use FAT-JAR with eclipse and any project with all its dependencies works without any problem.

Comment: @  Johnydep I am using netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your classes were in the package com.tst - go up one level in cmd (cd ..)  and type the following :  (use / on UNIX)

```
jar -cf myfile.jar .\com\tst\*\*.class
```

Now, if you have an existing JAR file, and want to extract it, you'd type the following

```
jar -xf myfile.jar
```

Manifest file can be used for specifying the jar version and classpath entries

Answer (score 0):

The manifest needs to be placed in the META-INF directory.

Reference: [Jar doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#The%20META-INF%20directory)