# Java Jar Ant include folder

Tags: java, ant, jar, directory

My Question is: How am i able to put files in a subdirectory into my jar via ant? Right now my Code is:

```
<jar destfile="${dist.dir}\wo42.jar" basedir="bin">
<manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.alternativedev.wo42.App" />
    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib" />
</manifest>
<zipgroupfileset dir="lib/." excludes="natives/*" />
<fileset dir="data/." includes="." />
```

It creates a structure like

```
ROOT-Jar
-org
--bla
-filefromdata1
-filefromdata2
```

But it should be

```
ROOT-Jar
-org
--bla
-data
--filefromdata1
--filefromdata2
```

Do You know what I mean?

Greetings, BigTeddy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include directory structure in an ant jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364531/how-to-include-directory-structure-in-an-ant-jar-file)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change the last line to

```
<fileset dir="." includes="data/**" />
```

No need to copy files around.

An alternative way (which is useful if you want to have the directory in the archive to have a different name) would be

```
<zipfileset dir="data" includes="." prefix="folder-name-in-jar"/>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that was the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you create the file structure you need and copy to it all the files required. Then you run jar command on the resulting root directory.

In order to copy files you can use the [ANT copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)
For example:

```
<copy todir="../dest/dir">
<fileset dir="." includes="data/**/*.java">
</fileset>
```

More on how to pack jar (basics) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276543/579580)